# Solving a scalar equation using matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, quadratics

I need to solve the following equation to find $x$ in $\mathbf{x}^T=[1,-x]$

$$(E[\mathbf{x^TAZ}])^2= \alpha^2Var[\mathbf{x^TAZ}]$$

where $\mathbf{Z} \sim N(\mathbf{m},\mathbf{\Sigma})$ is a vector of independent normal random variables, i.e $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a diagonal matrix.

One way of doing this is to express everything as scalars and to solve a quadratic qaution, but is there a way to do it with vector algebra? Maybe using a Moore-Penrose inverse? I only got to

$$(\mathbf{x^TA}E[\mathbf{Z}])^2= \alpha^2\mathbf{x^TA \Sigma A^Tx}$$

or by setting $\mathbf{x^TA} = \mathbf{c^T}$

$$(\mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{m})^2= \alpha^2 \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{\Sigma c}$$

and not sure how to proceed from here (if it is even possible to do so).

Comment: What should we know about $A$?

Comment: @N8tron Thank you for your message. There is nothing special about $A$. $x$ is $2 \times 1$, $A$ is $2 \times n$ and $Z$ is $n \times 1$.